# OpenCV on debian armhf

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the code working on gentoo x64 with opencv-2.4.5:

```
VideoCapture cap;
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS , 25);
cap.open(0);
Mat frame, edged;
cap >> frame;
Canny(frame, edged, 50, 200, 5);
```

but it doesnt work on debian armhf with opencv 2.3.

> OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats () in
>   cvCanny, file
>   /build/buildd-opencv_2.3.1-11-armhf-d9JIli/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/canny.cpp,
>   line 67 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>   what(): 
>   /build/buildd-opencv_2.3.1-11-armhf-d9JIli/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/canny.cpp:67:
>   error: (-210)  in function cvCanny

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

not really an answer, but ...

- 2.3.1 is *damn old* . no facereco, no stitching, baaa
- afaik, you can't set params on VideoCapture before opening it
- you want to check, if cap.open(0) actually succeeded, either the return value, or

  if ( ! cap.isOpened() ) // rrrr ;(
- some webcams need a 'warmup' time, and deliver empty/invalid frames on startup, so check

  if ( frame.empty() ) 
        continue; // play it again, sam

(your error message hints at an empty frame)